# Printing prime numbers between a range from slider input

Tags: javascript

I tried to print prime numbers between 1 to 1000 or to any number, and the output will display 1 which is not a prime number, but numbers other than 1 are working fine.

```
while (minValue< maxValue) {
       var flag = false;

        for(var i = 2; i <= minValue/2; ++i) {

            if(  minValue % i == 0 ) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }   
        }

        if (!flag)
            document.write(minValue+ " ");

        ++minValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minValue` is probably initialized to `1`. It should start at `2`.

Answer (score 0):

> the output will display 1 which is not a prime number,but numbers
>   other than 1 are working fine

1 is being displayed because if you pass `minValue` as 1, for-loop will be skipped and flag will stay `false`.

`if (!flag)` will stay true and that value (`1` in your case) is printed.

change your logic to

```
while ( minValue < maxValue ) {
     if ( minValue == 1 ) //this condition is added
     {
       ++minValue;
       continue;
     }
     var flag = false;
     for(var i = 2; i <= minValue/2; ++i) {
        if(  minValue % i == 0 ) {
           flag = true;
                break;
        }   
     }
     if (!flag)
     {
          document.write(minValue+ " ");
     }
     ++minValue;
}
```

Or even better, keep this condition before `while` loop, so that it is not executed for every loop run.